# Codeigniter array to capture multiple rows for POST variable

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and trying to capture multiple values from a single form to update my database.

Here is the controller:

```
    public function update_tb_table_test(){

        $tb_items = $_POST;
    }
```

And the view:

```
    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Payment ID</th>
                    <th>Customer ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update" id="comment_plog" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update2" id="ar_id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update3" id="date" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update" id="comment_plog" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update2" id="ar_id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update3" id="date" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update" id="comment_plog" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update2" id="ar_id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="update3" id="date" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

The result of print_r is

```
    Array ( [update] => 3 [update2] => 4 [update3] => 5 )
```

which are the last three values in my input boxes only from the last row. I know I need to loop through each row but I am not sure how to set this up. I have also tried `$tb_items = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);` and it only returns 5, the very last value.

I haven't included the model because I want to have the print_r returning the correct values before I move on to that. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
<input type="text" name="update[]" id="comment_plog" />
<input type="text" name="update2[]" id="ar_id" />
<input type="text" name="update3[]" id="date" />
```

Notice `[]` in the name. So you will get something like

```
Array ( [update] => Array( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 ) [update2] => Array( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 9 ) [update3] => Array( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 ) )
```

and can loop through each field like

```
foreach($_POST['update'] as $upd1)
{
    //...
}
```

and

```
foreach($_POST['update2'] as $upd2)
{
    //...
}
```

and so on.